# Portable org-mode export?

Tags: export, org-mode

Is it possible to create org-mode files, that behave independently of local emacs customization on export and, if possible, on display?

Org-mode has many features whose behavior depends on user customization. For instance, depending on `org-use-sub-superscripts` and `org-export-with-sub-superscripts`, a code `a^{b}_c` may be displayed (and exported) as either

- a<sup>b</sup><sub>c</sub>
- a<sup>b</sup>_c
- a^{b}_c

The export-behavior can be normalized by requiring that the export is performed in a clean Emacs process (`emacs -q`), but it would be a bit of a hack, and wouldn't work for the interactive behavior and display of the buffer.

Is there some way to make org-mode ignore all user-settings, except for those explicitly specified in the file?

Comment: Most of these settings can be overridden with in-buffer settings (`#+OPTIONS:`, etc.). So add these to your file.

Comment: A lot of settings cannot, however. E.g. if I use the ``#+latex_class: article`` but ``org-latex-classes`` has been redefined on another system, the document will compile incorrectly. This can be fixed with file-local variables, but there are way too many such variables to make this practical. Also for any `#+OPTIONS:` I miss, the targt machines possibly deviating defaults apply, so even that part isn't really robust.

Comment: emacs -q is not a hack: it is *the* way to ignore user settings. In combination with a load file that sets things exactly how you want, it is a portable way to do *exactly* the same thing on any platform.

Comment: @Nick Good point. What I meant mostly is, that it is *incomplete*, because it doesn't affect, e.g. display. Furthermore, it isn't straight forward, as org-mode latex export is quite likely to require setting `org-latex-classes`. Since the variable is not flagged as "safe", setting it as a file-variable would prevent export through an ``emacs --batch`` noninteractive session. ``emacs -q`` also wouldn't be aware that I have ``package-user-dir`` pointing to Dropbox. All kinds of (solvable) issues, that made wonder, if there is something like ``#+STARTUP: ignore-custom``

Comment: That's why I suggested the load file: it does the initializations that are needed (and only those) and has to be distributed along with the org-mode document.You might be able to include it in the org-mode document so that the processing is: 1) tangle to produde the load file and a command-line invocation and 2) invoke the command which does `emacs -q -l load-file.el`. I think that's about as self-sufficient as you can make it.